# A simple way to redirect users to their dashboards

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, dashboard

So being a newb at PHP still, I'm trying to figure  out a way that I can get certain users to their respective pages.

For example I would want the admin (once logged in) to be redirected to their admin page and no one else should see this page but the admin, as well as a tutor who should be redirected to their tutor page and no one else can see this but the tutor.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to wrap my mind around how to make this work as such and I have looked around to see other examples a lot of it not relating to what I am looking for as a lot of it is about "permissions".

Here is my code for the login page:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(-1);

ob_start();
session_start();

//connection to the database
require 'connection.php';

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{

  //query the databse for these columns in the table users
  $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, Username, Password, Role FROM users WHERE Username = :username');
  $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $records->execute();
  $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  //var_dump($results);

  // Count the results in the table if they are greater than 0
  // check the hashed password on the form and the password in the db match
  if((count($results) > 0) && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['Password'])) {
    //die('We have a log in');
    if ($results == 'Admin'){
      header('Location: adminPage.php');
    } else if ($results == 'Tutor'){
      header('Location: tutorPage.php');
    } else {
      header('Location: studentPage.php');
    }
  } else {
    //echo $_POST['password'];
    die('That user doesn\'t exist');
  }
}
?>
```

And after trying to execute the code of course some errors will follow:

```
[:error] [pid 1797] [client 127.0.0.1:37161] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /apps/bla/web/login.php on line 31, referer: http://hinat.local/loginPage.php
```

What do I need to take into consideration when trying to do this or what is the simplest way that I could go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address the `$results['Role']` as an array when testing the role, also it is a good idea to add an `exit;` after a `header('Location: ....);` as the header command does not stop code execution.

```
  if((count($results) > 0) && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['Password'])) {
    //die('We have a log in');
    if ($results['Role'] == 'Admin'){
      header('Location: adminPage.php');
      exit;
    } else if ($results['Role'] == 'Tutor'){
      header('Location: tutorPage.php');
      exit;
    } else {
      header('Location: studentPage.php');
      exit;
    }
  } else {
    //echo $_POST['password'];
    die('That user doesn\'t exist');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me. :)